# regex - line skipping

Tags: regex

I am using  basic regex parser called https://code.google.com/p/slre/ which has some basic regex set implementation. I wanted to parse http header which looks like

```
GET /3397557/RSVP006_male_468X60_05.swf HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Opera/9.80 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8.2) Presto/2.12.388 Version/12.10
Host: s0.2mdn.net
```

My intention is to get to "Host:", I am not bothered about User-Agent: line, so how do I have skip User-Agent line and move to Host: ? The expression I tried so far is pretty useless,

```
"^\\s*(GET|POST)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+HTTP/(\\d)\\.(\\d)\\s+User-Agent:\\s+.*?\\s+Host:\\s+(\\S+)"
```

I know that `User-Agent:\\s+.*?` is not how we skip the line, but I am not sure how to do it, any help?

Comment: The header I pasted got mangled, Actually each line will be new line because of "\r\n"

Comment: There's an edit button.

Comment: `/.*?\bHost: (.*)/s` -- something like that.  You need multiline matching (`s` in my example), then it's simple.

Comment: Sorry, Iam really new to this, I quite didnt understand what you mean? The above expression you posted will skip Host: altogether?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I am not familiar with your library, but the regex below works (implemented in javascript)

```
var str = "GET /3397557/RSVP006_male_468X60_05.swf HTTP/1.1"+
"User-Agent: Opera/9.80 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8.2) Presto/2.12.388 Version/12.10"+
"Host: s0.2mdn.net"

// capture the `Host` value
// has `m` flag to ensure multi-line capturing - not sure if you need to do that with
// your library, or even how to do that
var m = str.match(/Host:\s*(.+)/m)
// get the first captured match, which is the value of the `Host` field
console.log(m[1])
```

***EDIT: More careful regex***

- added newlines to the string (forgot that javascript needs them to be explicitly added)
- added `start marker` (`^`) the the start of the regex, so it will only match when `Host:` is at the beginning of a line

```
var str = "GET /3397557/RSVP006_male_468X60_05.swf HTTP/1.1\n"+
"User-Agent: Opera/9.80 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8.2) Presto/2.12.388 Version/12.10\n"+
"Host: s0.2mdn.net"

var m
if(m = str.match(/^Host:\s*(.+)/m)) // added `[\r\n]+`
  console.log(m[1]) // only if there is a match...
```

Comment: This matches the string `Host:` in any part of the header, so if you want to be very careful, you might want to add something at the start to ensure it only matches at the start of a line... I will update the answer now...